# How to pass a single argument that should have three values in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I have to call a webservice, that takes only one argument, but that argument should contain three values(UserName,Password,company) inside it. How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: You need to combine the three arguments into a single one in a way the web service recognises and can separate.  How you do this depending on the exact API you have, you would need to say exactly what you are doing.  Can you provide some code examples?

Comment: You find the single parameter that the service is expecting and you pass that. Impossible for anyone else to assist you with that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Java" way of doing this would be to construct a class that wraps these three values:

```
public class UserData {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String company;

    /* Constructor from the three parameters, getters, and possibly setters */
}
```

If you don't want to go through the hassle of creating a specific class for it, you could use some other, more generic, container, such as Apache Commons Lang's [Triple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the webservice method, this solution covers REST webservices. 
This is a GET example.

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/{name}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Person fetchPerson(
          @PathParam("id") Integer id,
          @PathParam("name") String name) {
```